# Express Gateway: 'warn: unable to verify the first certificate' Express.js

Tags: express, express-gateway

I'm brand new to Express Gateway and I'm trying to set up a basic API Gateway to link up some micro services. When I try and proxy to a specific end point https://my-service.net/status (not the real URL), I get this error

```
[EG:policy] warn: unable to verify the first certificate
```

I can access the URL 'https://my-service.net/status' in the browser just fine.

When I switch out the serviceEndPoint URL it works fine (e.g. to https://httpbin.org), so it seems like there's something different with my URL in terms of the SSL/authentication config.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

My gateway.config.yml -->

[image]

Comment: Hey,

this error is coming directly from OpenSSL — I'd really need to take a look to the real target URL to have a look into its certificate and see if there's anything wrong there.

Is there any way you could give us access to that?

Comment: Verify intermediate certificates are in the cert file.  Sometimes browsers automatically fill in the blanks, but really, such a a case is an SSL configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the SSL setup allows me to access the page from a browser (Chrome), but at the command line (e.g. through my Express Gateway which is served by NPM and running locally on port 8080) it fails.

[image]